# Show Flask dropdown on bootstrap frontend

Tags: python, html, reactjs, flask, bootstrap-4

I have a flask backend processing data and I have been able to generate a list of hospitals which I want to appear as a dropdown for selection on the dashboard. This is the code at the front end that I use

```
                <!--Hospitals select list-->
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown button
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" name="hospital" method="GET" action="/">
                            <option value="{{hospitals[0]}}" selected>{{hospitals[0]}}</option>
                            {% for hospital in hospitals[1:] %}
                            <option value="{{hospital}}" >{{hospital}}</option>
                            {%endfor%}
                        
                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

This code doesnt give a dropdown in a good style that can be used .see photo below [image]

I did like to get help on fixing this so that I can have a clean dropdown menu to be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a front-end issue. You don't need the bit that deals with the drop down button. Instead, I would just keep this bit

```
<select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" name="hospital">
    <option value="{{hospitals[0]}}" selected>{{hospitals[0]}}</option>
    {% for hospital in hospitals[1:] %}
        <option value="{{hospital}}" >{{hospital}}</option>
    {%endfor%}                        
</select>
```

You can also put it inside a div so that it starts on its own row

**Note:** A select doesn't need a GET or an action so I have dropped those attributes from the above code